# Quantification over structured sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, set-theory, foundations

I think we can't construct, for example,  the set of all vector spaces, because we can't construct the set of all sets.

However, there are theorems like "every vector space has a basis", which is a universal quantification of "$x$ has a basis" over the set of all vector spaces.

How do we quantify over structured sets?

Comment: There is no set of all sets but there is nothing wrong with saying "for all sets".  That's just what a universal quantifier does.

Comment: Think a bit more categorically. What the statement says is given any set with the properties of a vector space, there exists a basis. It says nothing about the collection of all such sets.

Comment: @EricWofsey Can I write $\forall x\in \text{VectorSpace} P(x)$ ?

Comment: @PONPON Hello, I am a noob but I am curious, why would you prefer to do that instead of using words?

Comment: @PONPON No, because as you said there is no set of all vector spaces. But you can say $\forall x (x \text{ is a vector space} \implies P(x))$, which achieves what you want.

Comment: @Jorge I think all mathematical statements can be written as logical formulas and I want to know how to do it.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think you can try to use this theory if you want to do something like that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory but I have no experience with it

Comment: What is a proof that there is no set containing all the vector spaces?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Briefly: let $F$ be a field and let $B$ be a set of cardinality $\geq |F| + \aleph_0$. Then the free $F$-vector space on $B$ has cardinality $|B|$, so there exists an $F$-vector space of every cardinality $\geq |F| + \aleph_0$. Thus, there cannot be a set of all $F$-vector spaces for the same reason there cannot be a set containing a set of each cardinality.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think somehow you need to use the set-theoretic definition of a vector space, which I guess also depends on how you define a tuple and some extra stuff.

Comment: True, and this can all be done! There are no problems. Or perhaps you're referring to my brief argument about why there is no set of all vector spaces? I'm certainly not claiming that such a set would contain a set of each cardinality (indeed, each vector space would be a tuple, which is finite). But you could use this set (plus the axiom schema of replacement) to produce a set whose elements have arbitrarily large cardinalities, and such a set cannot exist.

Comment: Vector spaces are a red herring here. One can say, every set has cardinality smaller than that of its power set, without commiting to a set of all sets.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how would you use that ?

Comment: @Jorge, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking me. One consequence is that there is no largest cardinality. It's also a simple way to show a beginner that not all infinite sets have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set theory is formalized in [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), where quantifiers range over the whole domain of discourse. For set theory, the domain of discourse is the universe of all sets, so every "for all" sentence is (in a sense) about *all* sets.

To "quantify over less", we use [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) statements: as pointed out in the comments, we can write "if $x$ is a vector space, then $x$ has a basis" as a first order formula $\varphi$ with free variable $x$, so $\forall x \varphi$ is a first-order sentence stating that every vector space has a basis. In this way, we can effectively quantify over any [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) definable by a formula.